# Title tag - Words usage vs Keyword spamming

Tags: seo, title

I am working for a small automobile dealership. I had a question regarding the usage of keywords in the title tag.

The problem I am facing is that:

The dealer name is XYZ Chevrolet. Here "XYZ" is the city name. If I target a keyword for e.g. XYZ Chevrolet Dealer or Chevrolet Dealer in XYZ. It clashes with the dealer name.

If I write a title like -

Chevrolet Dealer in XYZ | New & Used Vehicles | XYZ Chevrolet

will this be considered as spamming? I don't want my website to be penalized. We are a small dealership.

Comment: Keywords can be in any order, simply work on your off-page signals to establish the keyword intent for local search results.

Comment: Simon is right, whatever the order. Just use the clearer title for your users like: _Chevrolet Dealer in XYZ | Name of the company_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just put keyword one time on title tag. Title tag just 2-3 important keywords and don't repeat it.

closetnoc explain very clear and details in this post:

[How many times can I repeat a keyword without looking spammy to Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72382/how-many-times-can-i-repeat-a-keyword-without-looking-spammy-to-google?answertab=votes#tab-top)